# C# List & Sort URLs by FileName

Tags: c#, regex, sorting, uri, hyperlink

I want to make this:

```
anywhere.com/file/mybirthday.avi
anywhere.com/file/yourbirthday.avi
somewhere.com/file/mybirthday.avi
somewhere.com/file/yourbirthday.avi
```

To This:

```
anywhere.com/file/mybirthday.avi
somewhere.com/file/mybirthday.avi
##############
anywhere.com/file/yourbirthday.avi
somewhere.com/file/yourbirthday.avi
```

I found filenames with regex. And I sorted them. So my codes are here:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string gelenler = textBox2.Text;
    gelenler = gelenler.Replace("\r\n\r\n", "\r\n");
    string cikti = string.Empty;
    string regex = @"([^\/\\]+\.\w+)$";
    string[] parca = Regex.Split(gelenler, "\r\n");
    string[] parca2 = new string[parca.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < parca.Length; i++)
    {
        string ad = match(regex, parca[i]);
        parca2[i] = ad;
     }
     Array.Sort(parca2);

     for (int j = 0; j < parca2.Length; j++)
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < parca2.Length; i++)
         {
            if (parca2[i].IndexOf(match(regex,parca[j]))!=-1)
            {
               textBox1.Text += parca[i] + Environment.NewLine;
               parca[i] = "";
             }
             textBox1.Text += "#############" + Environment.NewLine;
          }

      }
}

private string match(string regex, string html, int i = 1)
{
     return new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.Multiline).Match(html).Groups[i].Value.Trim();
}
```

But didn't working. Any ideas ?

//Sorry my English

Comment: When/how do you want "##############" to be printed?

Comment: Filename1.avi
Filename1.avi
Filename1.avi
##############
Filename2.avi
Filename2.avi
Filename2.avi

Comment: Can you check the code I've posted - do you intend to group according to filenames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think always the best idea is to use existing .net framework stuff, as in this case `Path.GetFileName`:

```
        var strings = new[]
                      {
                          "anywhere.com/file/mybirthday.avi",
                          "anywhere.com/file/yourbirthday.avi",
                          "somewhere.com/file/mybirthday.avi",
                          "somewhere.com/file/yourbirthday.avi"
                      };

        strings = strings.OrderBy(x => Path.GetFileName(x)).ToArray();

        foreach (var s in strings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);                
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Uri class. Use the Segements property in order to get the file name (it will be the last segment).

```
var uris = new[]
{
   new Uri("http://anywhere.com/file/mybirthday.avi"),
   new Uri("http://anywhere.com/file/yourbirthday.avi"),
   new Uri("http://somewhere.com/file/mybirthday.avi"),
   new Uri("http://somewhere.com/file/yourbirthday.avi")
};

var filename = uris.OrderBy(x => x.Segments[x.Segments.Length - 1]).ToArray();
foreach (var f in filename)
{
   Console.WriteLine(f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean grouping the files; in which case the following code can be used:

```
        IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, string>> groups = strings.GroupBy(x => Path.GetFileName(x)).OrderBy(g => g.Key);
        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            foreach (var str in group)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(str);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("#############");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I did merge the **Giedrius** and yours codes. its working. //sorry my English again :)